# Does Craft parse requests inside a conditional if it is false?

Tags: conditional

Does Craft parse the contents of a false/negative/empty conditional statement? So would you take a performance hit if you had a big chunk of code inside a conditonal that was false?

```
{% set foo = "foo" %}
{% if foo == foo %}Small code {% else %} MASSIVE CODE{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes,** Twig will parse it all down to PHP before running it. It stores the rendered PHP in a `/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/` file.

**No,** Craft will not run anything inside the conditional if it's `false`. At that point, it's simply processing exactly as normal PHP would.

So no, you shouldn't be notably penalized for anything inside a falsey `if` statement.